# Is it fine to use "the second largest" when comparing 3 things

Tags: comparatives, ielts

*Let's say, if there were 4 cities, A, B, C and D*

> - 1,000 people live in city A.
> - 2,000 people live in city B.
> - 3,000 people live in city C.
> - 4,000 people live in city D.

**`- The second largest number of people lives in city C.`**

The sentence above would be considered fine.

---

---

*What if there were only 3 cities, A, B, and C, where now we could use the word "intermediate".*

> - 1,000 people live in city A.
> - 2,000 people live in city B.
> - 3,000 people live in city C.

**`1) The second largest number of people lives in city B.`** OR

**`2) The intermediate number of people lives in city B.`**

***So the question is: which one is better?***

*`Or if there's a better way to express the intention, please suggest it.`*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second largest works, but the phrase that first came to mind for me when I read your question was, next to largest. I think I'd use that in this case.

Intermediate feels more like a word that is used in context of form or phase or state. I don't think I'd prefer it when describing something as static as numbers

Comment: **Thank you, I really appreciate your answer,** but I'm not a native speaker, and l'm not sure how to use it. *Can you show me some examples for the phrase* ***"next to largest"*** *please?*

Comment: One example can be formed from your question itself: "In which city do the next to largest number of people live?"